# Django deployment with nginx & gunicorn (godaddy domain/amazon ec2 instance)

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, dns

Ok, so I'm a website newbie who just finished the django tutorial, and decided to try and publish my polls app on the net. So far I have a godaddy domain name which I'm trying to point to my amazon EC2 instance's elastic IP which is currently hosting my polls website.

Currently what I have set up is:

Amazon route 53: Hosted zone that points to mydomain.com with record sets of: name mydomain.com & www.mydomain.com and Value xx.xxx.xx.x

Godaddy: DNS zone file: A(Host) to my amazon elastic IP xx.xxx.xx.x, Nameservers to the 4 amazon route 53 hosted zone nameservers.

EC2 instance: running nginx and gunicorn to host the app.

My issue is that I can go to the website with amazon's elastic IP, but I cannot access it with the domain name (I get a bold "Welcome to nginx!" page no matter if i try to go to the home page or the /polls/1 page.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks about right.  Have you followed the standard gunicorn configs with nginx ?

http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html

You probably want something like this on your nginx configs:

```
http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log /tmp/nginx.access.log combined;
    sendfile on;

    upstream app_server {
        server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
        # For a TCP configuration:
        # server 192.168.0.7:8000 fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 default;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        server_name _;
        ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate      /usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.key;

        keepalive_timeout 5;

        # path for static files
        root /path/to/app/current/public;

        location / {
            # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
            try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
        }

        location @proxy_to_app {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_pass   http://app_server;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
        location = /500.html {
            root /path/to/app/current/public;
        }
    }
}
```

You want to point to the right SSL cert and key paths (instead of `/usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.pem;` and `/usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.key;`). Also, you should point root to your specific Django static files instead of `/path/to/app/current/public`

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out.

Nginx was listening to 127.0.0.1:8000 and gunicorn was broadcasting to 127.0.0.1:8001. (502 error)

To fix the DNS issue, I had to go onto my amazon EC2 control panel and open up port 8000.